# :: method in List - contravariant argument type

Tags: scala, generics

A simple question. The method `::` of class immutable `List` is defined as:

> sealed abstract class List[+A] ...
>
> def ::[B >: A](x: B): List[B]

Suppose say I have:

```
class Fruit
class Mango extends Fruit
scala> val d:List[Fruit] = List.empty[Fruit]
d: List[Fruit] = List()

scala> new Mango :: d
res5: List[Fruit] = List(Mango@272d6774)
```

Now I am confused here. As per `::` declaration, the argument type should be contravariant. i.e. in this case any class that `>: Fruit` (I understand why it is made that way). But what I dont get is, `Mango <: Fruit`, so why doesn't the compiler throw error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
new Mango :: d
```

you expect the compiler to reason: "`new Mango` has type `Mango` and `d` has type `List[Fruit]`, so `List[Fruit].::(Mango)` needs to typecheck, which it doesn't". In this case it would indeed be an error.

But in fact, it reasons differently: "I need `new Mango :: d` to typecheck, so `new Mango` must have *some* type `B` such that `B :> Fruit`. Is there such a `B`? Yes, `B = Fruit`." So there is no error.

Answer (score 5):

You would still be able to add the `Mango` to `d` even if `List` was invariant, simply because `Mango` is still a `Fruit`. Think about it in terms of a plain old java list:

```
val d = new java.util.ArrayList[Fruit]
d.add(new Mango)
```

So the contravariance doesn't restrict your ability to add subtypes - it enables you to add supertypes and get a compiler-checked list type back from it:

```
val d: List[Fruit] = Nil
val a: List[Plant] = new Carrot :: d
```

Comment: Yes agreed. That is the property of `List`. But here the method puts restrictions on the type of arguments. It should be `_ >: Fruit` but its behaving as `_ <: Fruit`

Comment: No, it isn't behaving as `_ <: Fruit`. If it did, `new Object :: d` wouldn't work (and it actually does).

Comment: I try to rephrase it: the method expects an argument of type `B` which is a *non-strict* supertype of `A`, i.e. `B >: A`. The resulting list would have the *most specific common supertype*. E.G. when `A = Fruit` and `B = Mango` you end up with a `List[Fruit]`; when `A = Fruit` and `B = Plant` you get a `List[Plant]`. To sum up: the method is designed to let you build more general type containers, and not to restrict you from adding a specific subtype (which, btw, wouldn't be possible as per Liskov)